# Dynamically apply CSS styles in iframe using Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have an iframe content containing multiple classes.i.e, **header, footer**

I want to apply css styles for these classes dynamically using jquery,

I try to apply only for **header** in the following way, but how do i apply for footer(if we have multiple classes) dynamically.

```
$('#iframe').find('.header').css({
            'color': objProp.cssstyles['header']['color'],
            'background-color': objProp.cssstyles[pageSection]['background']                
        });
```

i have a json data,

```
var objProp = {            
        "cssstyles": {
            "header": {
                "background": "#FFFFFF",
                "color": "#959597"
            },               
            "footer": {
                "background": "#2b9ef0",
                "color": "#f7992d"                  
            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: Did you manage to change any styles of anything yet in the iframe? By the looks of the code you showing, it doesn't look like you'd succeed with the header.Need the HTML of the page and the HTML of the page inside the iframe. If you do not control the page within the iframe, then forget the whole idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer to below code for an idea. This demo HTML doesn't contains any `iframe` but i think you can manage it as per your HTML
Please refer to jQuery's [.css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/#css-properties) documentation for further help.

```js
var objProp = {            
        "cssstyles": {
            "header": {
                "background": "#FFFFFF",
                "color": "#959597"
            },               
            "footer": {
                "background": "#2b9ef0",
                "color": "#f7992d"                  
            }
        }
    };

$(document).ready(function(){
  var cssStyles = objProp["cssstyles"];
  for(var key in cssStyles){
    var cssObjToApply = cssStyles[key];
    $("."+key).css(cssObjToApply);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header">
  this is header
</div>  
<div class="footer">
  this is footer
</div>
```